# <a href="www.example.com">example</a> redirects to mysite.com/www.example.com?

Tags: html

Example:

```
<a href="www.example.com"> Click here to go to www.example.com!</a>
```

and

```
<a href="http://www.example.com"> Click here to go to www.example.com!</a>
```

The first one redirects to the following URL: `http://www.currentsite.com/www.example.com`
while the second one works perfectly fine.

here's the code I'm using: (ruby on rails)

```
<%=h link_to @user.details.website, @user.details.website, :class => 'link'%>
```

The only solution I have would be checking for `http://` and add it if it's not already there.

Comment: this is expected behavior because that is how html has always worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why, yes. URIs *not starting* with `/` or `...://` are *relative URIs* and are resolved against the current URI. Your browser has no idea that you *mean* "www.example.com" to be a domain name, because it's also a perfectly valid path name and looks like a relative URI.

You have three choices:

- start from the protocol (`http://example.com`) to link to different protocols and/or domains
- start with a `/` to link to a different absolute path within the current domain
- link to relative paths from the current path within the current domain

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly your question is but:

You need to include http:// in your href link unless you are linking to a file on your server.